# The nested query is not supported. Operation1='UnionAll' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I have the following query.

```
var query = Repository.Query<Product>()
    .Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.Article.ArticleSections.Count() > 0)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        OfficeId = p.TariffCategory.Office.Id,
        Office = p.TariffCategory.Office.Name,
        Category = p.TariffCategory.Description,
        ArticleId = p.Article.Id,
        Article = p.Article.Title,
        Destinations = p.ProductDestinations.OrderBy(pd => pd.Destination.Description).Select(pd => new { Id = pd.DestinationId, Name = pd.Destination.Description }),
        GlobalDestinations = p.AllDestinationsInOffice,
        p.Article.LastReviewedDate,
        p.Article.CreatedDate,
        p.Article.CreatedByEmployee
    });
query = query.Concat(Repository.Query<Package>()
    .Where(pkg => !pkg.IsDeleted && pkg.Article.ArticleSections.Count() > 0)
    .Select(pkg => new
    {
        OfficeId = pkg.TariffCategory.Office.Id,
        Office = pkg.TariffCategory.Office.Name,
        Category = pkg.TariffCategory.Description,
        ArticleId = pkg.Article.Id,
        Article = pkg.Article.Title,
        Destinations = pkg.PackageDestinations.OrderBy(pd => pd.Destination.Description).Select(pd => new { Id = pd.DestinationId, Name = pd.Destination.Description }),
        GlobalDestinations = pkg.AllDestinationsInOffice,
        pkg.Article.LastReviewedDate,
        pkg.Article.CreatedDate,
        pkg.Article.CreatedByEmployee
    }));
query = query.Concat(Repository.Query<Backgrounder>()
    .Where(bkgd => !bkgd.IsDeleted && bkgd.Article.ArticleSections.Count() > 0)
    .Select(bkgd => new
    {
        OfficeId = bkgd.TariffCategory.Office.Id,
        Office = bkgd.TariffCategory.Office.Name,
        Category = bkgd.TariffCategory.Description,
        ArticleId = bkgd.Article.Id,
        Article = bkgd.Article.Title,
        Destinations = bkgd.BackgrounderDestinations.OrderBy(bd => bd.Destination.Description).Select(bd => new { Id = bd.DestinationId, Name = bd.Destination.Description }),
        GlobalDestinations = bkgd.AllDestinationsInOffice,
        bkgd.Article.LastReviewedDate,
        bkgd.Article.CreatedDate,
        bkgd.Article.CreatedByEmployee
    }));

// Apply filters
if (OfficeIds.Any())
    query = query.Where(a => OfficeIds.Contains(a.OfficeId));
if (DestinationIds.Any())
    query = query.Where(a => a.GlobalDestinations || a.Destinations.Any(d => DestinationIds.Contains(d.Id)));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ArticleTitle))
    query = query.Where(a => a.Article.Contains(ArticleTitle));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TariffCategory))
    query = query.Where(a => a.Category.Contains(TariffCategory));

// Sort results
query = query.OrderBy(a=> a.Office).ThenBy(a => a.Category).ThenBy(a => a.Article);

var articles = query.ToList();
```

However, when I run this query I get an exception.

> The nested query is not supported. Operation1='UnionAll' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'

The query searches through articles in my database. Because articles can be related to a `Product`, `Package` or `Backgrounder`, and I need information from the related table, I concatenate separate queries for each of those items.

I've narrowed it down to the assignment to `Destinatons`. Apparently, this constitute a query within the query associated with `Concat()`. (If I remove the second two queries and the associated `Concat()` calls, it works fine.)

After looking at this a while, I'm having trouble seeing another way to construct my query without making it much, much slower.

Does anyone see any tricks I might have missed to work around the exception?

Comment: Unfortunately no tricks can make working a `Concat` / `Union` query that includes collections members inside the projection, except executing them separately and merging the result in memory. The filters can be applied to each query, but the sorting should also be in memory. Hope you have no paging.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Right. The other option is to base the query on my `Article` table, but then getting information from the related table--which can be one of three types--becomes messy. (No paging at this point.)

Comment: Even if you start from `Article` table, I don't see how you can get to `Destinations`

Comment: @IvanStoev: Well, if I start with the `Article` table then I could put everything in a single query and so accessing the destinations might no longer be a nested query. If would need some sort of conditional code that gets data from the related object, depending on what type of related object was involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no tricks. The only reasonable way I see to make this work without totally rewriting it is to execute the queries separately (applying all possible filters) and then do `Concat` and ordering in memory like this:

```
var queries = new [] 
{
    Repository.Query<Product>()
    .Where(p => !p.IsDeleted && p.Article.ArticleSections.Count() > 0)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        OfficeId = p.TariffCategory.Office.Id,
        Office = p.TariffCategory.Office.Name,
        Category = p.TariffCategory.Description,
        ArticleId = p.Article.Id,
        Article = p.Article.Title,
        Destinations = p.ProductDestinations.OrderBy(pd => pd.Destination.Description).Select(pd => new { Id = pd.DestinationId, Name = pd.Destination.Description }),
        GlobalDestinations = p.AllDestinationsInOffice,
        p.Article.LastReviewedDate,
        p.Article.CreatedDate,
        p.Article.CreatedByEmployee
    }),

    Repository.Query<Package>()
    .Where(pkg => !pkg.IsDeleted && pkg.Article.ArticleSections.Count() > 0)
    .Select(pkg => new
    {
        OfficeId = pkg.TariffCategory.Office.Id,
        Office = pkg.TariffCategory.Office.Name,
        Category = pkg.TariffCategory.Description,
        ArticleId = pkg.Article.Id,
        Article = pkg.Article.Title,
        Destinations = pkg.PackageDestinations.OrderBy(pd => pd.Destination.Description).Select(pd => new { Id = pd.DestinationId, Name = pd.Destination.Description }),
        GlobalDestinations = pkg.AllDestinationsInOffice,
        pkg.Article.LastReviewedDate,
        pkg.Article.CreatedDate,
        pkg.Article.CreatedByEmployee
    }),

    Repository.Query<Backgrounder>()
    .Where(bkgd => !bkgd.IsDeleted && bkgd.Article.ArticleSections.Count() > 0)
    .Select(bkgd => new
    {
        OfficeId = bkgd.TariffCategory.Office.Id,
        Office = bkgd.TariffCategory.Office.Name,
        Category = bkgd.TariffCategory.Description,
        ArticleId = bkgd.Article.Id,
        Article = bkgd.Article.Title,
        Destinations = bkgd.BackgrounderDestinations.OrderBy(bd => bd.Destination.Description).Select(bd => new { Id = bd.DestinationId, Name = bd.Destination.Description }),
        GlobalDestinations = bkgd.AllDestinationsInOffice,
        bkgd.Article.LastReviewedDate,
        bkgd.Article.CreatedDate,
        bkgd.Article.CreatedByEmployee
    }),
};

// Apply filters
if (OfficeIds.Any())
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.Length; i++) queries[i] = queries[i].Where(a => OfficeIds.Contains(a.OfficeId));
if (DestinationIds.Any())
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.Length; i++) queries[i] = queries[i].Where(a => a.GlobalDestinations || a.Destinations.Any(d => DestinationIds.Contains(d.Id)));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ArticleTitle))
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.Length; i++) queries[i] = queries[i].Where(a => a.Article.Contains(ArticleTitle));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TariffCategory))
    for (int i = 0; i < queries.Length; i++) queries[i] = queries[i].Where(a => a.Category.Contains(TariffCategory));

// Switch to LINQ to Objects and concatenate the results
var result = queries.Select(query => query.AsEnumerable()).Aggregate(Enumerable.Concat);

// Sort results
result = result.OrderBy(a=> a.Office).ThenBy(a => a.Category).ThenBy(a => a.Article);

var articles = result.ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This is the basic approach I ended up taking.

Comment: I've also hit this problem and I solved it by executing one of my queries. The use case was dynamic filtration, involving multiple filters, composed with **OR** operator. Could you please elaborate as to when exactly does this happen, because I can't really grasp it atm. Or, if you happen to know a good read on the subject?

Comment: @Alex It happens when you try to `Union` / `Concat` queries which contain correlated subqueries (collections like `Destinations` above)

Comment: @IvanStoev So the problem in this case lies inside `Destinations = p.ProductDestinations.OrderBy(pd => pd.Destination.Description).Select(pd => new { Id = pd.DestinationId, Name = pd.Destination.Description })`?